# Use pandas pivot_table() to convert attribute-value pairs to table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of attribute,value pairs like this:

```
date,01-01-2018
product,eggs
price, 5
date,01-10-2018
product,milk
price,3
```

And I want to create a table like

```
date,product,price
01-01-2018,eggs,5
01-10-2018,milk,3
```

I've tried adding headers 'attributes' and attribute_values', creating an arbitrary column "values" and using

```
pd.pivot_table(av_pairs, index="value", columns=av_pairs.attributes, values=av_pairs.attribute_values)
```

The error is

```
pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Using stack() also didn't work.  Can anyone point out what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html) and count new indices by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
print (df)
         a           b
0     date  01-01-2018
1  product        eggs
2    price           5
3     date  01-10-2018
4  product        milk
5    price           3

df1 = pd.pivot(index=df.groupby('a').cumcount(),
              columns=df['a'],
              values=df['b'])
```

Or use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index([df.groupby('a').cumcount(), 'a'])['b'].unstack()

print (df1)
a        date price product
0  01-01-2018     5    eggs
1  01-10-2018     3    milk
```